# How to create color and display color attribute filters for configurable products in magento 1.8

Tags: javascript, php

I want to display search by color and search by size filters in category page for configurable products. I have created color and size attributes, but those attributes are not showing while creating products.

Answer (score 0):

hope this works for you

if u have created custom color attribute check weather the attribute
from admin->catalog->attributes->manage attribute

select your attribute and goto edit 
then check

Properties->Frontend Properties-> 
for forntend settings (search,advance search,Sorting) of attribute

Answer (score 0):

- Go to **Catalog** >> **Attributes** >> **Manage Attribute Sets**.
- Click on appropriate attribute set in which you want to assign newly created attribute.
- A new page will open where on right hand side you will see **Unassigned Attributes**. From here you need to drag and drop color and size (or any other attribute as per your requirement) under respective group.
- Click on **Save Attribute Set** button.

Now check by adding new product or editing existing product.

Please let me know if you have any other query.